# Proof of an inequality regarding the norm of a matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, matrix-equations, matrix-norms

I've found this inequality being used a lot in papers but have been unable to prove it for myself.

Consider a matrix polynomial $P(z)=A_{m}z^{m}+...+A_0$ with complex matrix coefficients.
Then, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $P(z)$ and some unit eigenvector $x\in \mathbb{C}^m$ associated with $\lambda$, we have
$$||P(\lambda)x|| \geqslant ||A_{m}\lambda^{m}x||-||A_{m-1}\lambda^{m-1}x+...+A_0x||$$

Comment: Isn’t it just the triangle inequality?
$$
\|P(\lambda)x\|=\|A_m\lambda^mx+\big(P(\lambda)x-A_m\lambda^mx\big)\|\ge\|A_m\lambda^mx\|-\|P(\lambda)x-A_m\lambda^mx\|.
$$